# Laravel API update/edit function

Tags: php, laravel, function, api, edit

```php
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $bridge = Bridge::where('bridge_id',$id);
    $bridge->bridge_id = $request->bridge_id;
    $bridge->bridge_name = $request->bridge_name;
    $bridge->bridge_description = $request->bridge_description;
    $bridge->bridge_region = $request->bridge_region;
    $bridge->latitude = $request->latitude;
    $bridge->longitude = $request->longitude;
    $bridge->save();
}
```

I am confused because if this `$id`. i have no `increments('id')` column since I changed it to `string('bridge_id')` in my table. I cant get update/edit to work.

this is the error message:

> BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::save() in file C:\xampp\htdocs\PhilSIMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 50

Comment: add `first` in your query: `$bridge = Bridge::where('bridge_id',$id)->first();`

Comment: it has a different error now : Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;id&#039;

Answer (score 2):

The first error is pretty clear:

> BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::save()

this is because you are calling the `->save()` method in the Query Builder instead of an actual Model (`Bridge`) instance. To solve this, first retrieve the element to update with the `->first()` method.

```php
$bridge = Bridge::where('bridge_id',$id)->first();
// Instead of: $bridge = Bridge::where('bridge_id',$id);
```

Or even better, given that you need to find an element.. why don't use that method?

```php
$bridge = Bridge::find($id);
```

Check the documentation regarding this topic: [Retrieving Single Models / Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models).

---

Then, the next error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column `id`

seems to be because Laravel doesn't know that your primmary key is `bridge_id` instead of `id`. By default, Laravel will look up for a primmary key named `id` if no custom primmary key is specified.

To solve this, go to your `Bridge` model and add this:

```php
// Bridge.php
protected $primaryKey = 'bridge_id';
```

To more information related to [Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! THIS HELPED ME WITH MY PROBLEM! :D

Comment: @jediArvin Glad to help. You can now accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

add `first` in your query: `$bridge = Bridge::where('bridge_id',$id)->first();`

Comment: it has a different error now : Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;id&#039

Comment: can you add your `routes` and `view` function?

Comment: Route::get('bridges', 'BridgeController@index');
Route::post('addbr', 'BridgeController@store');
Route::get('bridge/{id}', 'BridgeController@show');
Route::delete('bridge/{id}', 'BridgeController@destroy');
Route::post('editbr/{id}', 'BridgeController@edit');

Comment: public function show($id)
    {
        $bridge = Bridge::where('bridge_id', $id)->first();
        return Response::json($bridge);
    }